# Error when creating android project with older API

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop

I've updated Android 5.0.1 (API21). When I create project with Android 5.0.1. It's Ok. 
But if I create Android with older API then the project will get errors. 
Support library "appcompat_v7" will get Error "No resource found"[image: Error when change API of appcompat_v7]

I found a solution in stackoverflow, change the API of appcompat_v7 to 5.0.1. But when i change, my project will get errors. Class R didn't create when i created project.

[image: Error when crate android project]

I'm newbie. Please help me. How can i resolve these errors.

The result after Ctrl+Shift+O
[image: The result after resolving]

Comment: Did you remove android-support-v4.jar in your project libs directory? sometimes the signature mismatch will prevent the tool to build the resources.

Comment: I didn't remove anything. :( I just created project.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps :

1. Right click on your `Project root` -> Go to `Android Tools` -> `Add Support Library` -> A dialog would popup, `Accept License` -> Click `Install`
2. Do the same for your `appcompat_v7` Library

**OR**

Just copy and paste the `support library` from your project `libs` directory to `appcompat_v7` `libs` directory to avoid support library signature mismatch.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: But the problem is that class R isn't created when i created project with older API.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and check if any of your JAVA files is importing android.R in it, If that's true, remove it from there, or  use **Ctrl + Shift + O** keyboard shortcut!, Let me know if it won't work.

Comment: Sometimes **R.java** won't generate, when any of your **xml** files contains an error, go to **Problems** tab at the bottom of your editor and check whether any **xml** file contains an error.Let me know if it won't work! @user3295337

Comment: the project isn't changed and no errors in any xml file. :(

Comment: I will edit my post for you can see the result after use ctrl+Shift+O.

Comment: I meant to say that did you tried my answer, not my comment, Please check my answer again, and to as mentioned and then let me know if it won't work.

Comment: Yes, of course. About copying solution, the library in project is existed in appcompat

Comment: Yeah I know, it exists,but to remove the signature mismatch, you should delete that and add corresponding library from your main project.

Comment: I did and cleaned the project. But it still get the problem "R cannot be resolved"